# CakePHP function for default view, where to put

Tags: php, cakephp

When I have a function which needs to be executed on every page **and** assigns a variable to the default layout, where should I add the function?

I was thinking about the AppController where I add a private function and call this private function in the beforeFilter function where I then assign it to a view variable, but is this the right way to do this?

Small example of what I mean:

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->set('something', $this->someFunction());
    }

    private function someFunction(){
        return 'something';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right, your example looks good. beforeFilter() or beforeRender() is a good place for that. Just don't forget to cache your data except it changes on each page.

Comment: Alright thanks, just wanted to confirm that I'm doing it the right way.